# How much shall I wait until the sending buffer of a socket is empty?

Tags: c++, sockets, getsockopt

I am trying to throttle my network of only one receiver.

Firstly,I detect the size of SO_SNDBUF by :

```
getsockopt(sendsockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sndBufferSize, &sbsLen);
```

Then, I keep filling up this buffer until it is entirely full by :

```
if (sndBufferSize - NbBytesInBuffer >= HEADER){
    memcpy (sendBuffer + NbBytesInBuffer, &buf_header, HEADER);
    NbBytesInBuffer +=HEADER;
}
```

Ofcourse, I am mentioning just the relevant part of my code.

Finally, when the buffer is full, write to socket.

```
if (sndBufferSize - NbBytesInBuffer < HEADER)
sentSize = write(sendsockfd,sendBuffer,NbBytesInBuffer);
...
```

My problem is not mentioned yet. All the above stuff are working perfectly until I want to resend data again.

Now, because I want to send in the maximum possible rate, I have to wait as less as possible. (i.e. I have to resend right away the send buffer is empty).

How to detect the needed time for `write()` in order to re-empty the sending buffer (in the most optimum way)?

P.S. Please don't tell me to wait arbitrary time (for instance `usleep(10000);`)

Comment: Have you considered `select` ?

Comment: I have only one receiver. I edited my question

Comment: `select` works also with one `fd`, can tell if you can read or write to a specific `fd` and has a *timeout*.

Comment: This sounds massively like over-engineering.

Comment: @Jarod42, Indeed, this won't solve the problem because what if select returns 'not available yet'. So , I have to use a loop. And then, wait within the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to send at the maximum rate, `write` should block by default when needed. As soon as `write` returns, it's done with your `sendBuffer` and you can put the next block of data into it and call `write` again.

You only have to mess with `select` if you set up the socket as nonblocking, and in that case the condition you're waiting for is that the socet is writable.

Comment: You are right. This is what I am thinking about. Just let me check it.

Comment: I don't know what is going on. But, I tried this before and I faced some memory problems :) Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, if you have a really optimistic OS with huge buffers or some similar oddness, you can get into a situation where you can run out of memory making a gigantic send buffer. One exercise to try is to time how long it takes to transfer a fixed amount of data with different block sizes (e.g. transfer 10 MB in 4kB, 8kB, 16kB, ... 1024kB blocks). There comes a point where bigger buffers don't help.

Comment: Ok, thank you. This would have been my next question :)

Comment: By the way, does it make sense to fix message size and increase/decrease window/packet size? In other words, does it has impact on the throughput? The trivial answer is yes. So, what is the difference?

Comment: If you're using TCP/IP, the network stack should take care of optimizing the necessary parameters. In this case, whatever size you `write` will be broken up ("fragmented") into IP packets of up to the [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit), which is usually either 1500 or 9000 bytes. The stack will try to optimize throughput by adjusting how many of these packets it will transmit before expecting to get acknowledgements for any of them. Mucking with window sizes will probably mess with these adjustments, if anything.